# How to read a http response body when tyring to read http via tcp socket?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, tcp, mxml

So I want to read http streams using flash tcp sockets. I do not really need the http header at all - all I need is body which contains flv. so how to read http response body into byte array using flash sockets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are sockets a must-have requirement?

You could use [as3httpclientlib](http://code.google.com/p/as3httpclientlib/) instead?

It throws a different event for headers and data (onStatus, onData), so you wouldn't need to re-invent the wheel.

Alternatively, if it doesn't work, the source code is available, might help for what you need.

Comment: hm... interesting... can  as3httpclientlib load infinite (meaning streams with undetermined size) partly (meaning by some portions like 100kbs) and give any event each time it gets a peace of new data?

Comment: On the examples page, the onData handler has the comment "Notified with response content in event.bytes as it streams in" so I'm guessing yes, but I haven't used it like that

Comment: Arent you re-inventing the NetStream class though?